# Visual Studio 2010 Chart control - line color

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, charts

How do I change the color of the horizonal and vertical lines? I'd like to make them a little lighter, yet leave the X and Y axis black, probably.

[image]

Edited:

indyfromoz suggestion resulted in this:
[image]

The effect I want is this:
[image]

(Subtler horiz and vertical lines, maybe even no vertical lines.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**VB**

```
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(&H50, &H9C, &H9A, &H95)
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(&H50, &H9C, &H9A, &H95)
```

**C#**

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(50, 200, 200, 200);
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(50, 200, 200, 200);
```

Comment: Bingo. Sweet, to the point, and not the first thing that Google returned.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options - use the Axis.IsInterlaced property or the Axis.StripLines property. This page is a [handy reference for customization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489216.aspx) of the grid lines in a chart.

Here is some sample C# code (from the above reference) -

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines.Add(new StripLine()); 
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines[0].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(80, 252, 180, 65); 
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines[0].StripWidth = 40; 
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines[0].Interval = 10000; 
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines[0].IntervalOffset **
```

HTH, indyfromoz

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please see my updated post. BTW, Was the last line (**) a typo , not sure what it means.