# How to change the colour and style of MajorGrid of AxisY in ASP.net chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I made a chart in asp.net and I want to change the color of the MajorGrid to light grey and style to dash. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this post will help you to change color of grid but keep AXIS same [Visual Studio 2010 Chart control - line color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040244/visual-studio-2010-chart-control-line-color).

For line style `Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dash;`

Comment: Great, this I extracted and it worked for me.
<MajorGrid Enabled ="true" LineColor = "gray" /> for colour. I will try style later.